# What actually contains reference to JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

1. What stuff contains reference to JavaScript object(or function)? Address in RAM of begining object's code or anything else?
2. And how I can see this stuff?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In computer programming everything is stored either in memory or on disk. As for how you can see it: that's even more puzzling question. What exactly do you want to see? How physically it is stored? It's memory address? It's internal JavaScript structure? How it is implemented in C?

Comment: In C language pointers contain address in RAM. I want to see is reference in JS the same? Or if not - what is it?

Comment: It is pretty much the same under the hood (actually they are implemented as `void*`). Most JavaScript engines are written in C/C++ after all. However it is well wrapped and generally it is impossible to get that address.

Comment: Big thanks. You are answer to my question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it's sandboxed.

You have RAM > Browser memory > sandbox > webpage text > Dom tree > jsevents & functions & variables.

Usually it's guarded that nothing can get out of the sandbox. Don't know about getting into the sandbox what you are talking about.

Comment: First of all: not necessarily "browser" memory (JavaScript is also used outside of the browser world). Secondly: JavaScript objects are independent of webpage text and dom tree (it should be directly under sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

1. Its there in browser memory in RAM. I am not sure about `What stuff contains reference to JavaScript object(or function)` part...
2. If you can see browser's memory from RAM address, then you may get access to that object, too!!